# The proof of shrinking coefficients using ridge regression through "spectral decomposition"

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regularization, ridge-regression, svd

I have understood how ridge regression shrinks coefficients towards zero geometrically.
Moreover I know how to prove that in the special "Orthonormal Case," but I am confused how that works in the general case via "Spectral decomposition."

Comment: You have stated you are confused, but what is your question?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The question appears to ask for a demonstration that Ridge Regression shrinks coefficient estimates towards zero, using a spectral decomposition.  The spectral decomposition can be understood as an easy consequence of the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD).  Therefore, this post starts with SVD.  It explains it in simple terms and then illustrates it with important applications.  Then it provides the requested (algebraic) demonstration.  (The algebra, of course, is identical to the geometric demonstration; it merely is couched in a different language.)

---

##What the SVD is

Any $n\times p$ matrix $X$, with $p \le n$, can be written $$X = UDV^\prime$$ where

1. $U$ is an $n\times p$ matrix.

   - The columns of $U$ have length $1$.
   - The columns of $U$ are mutually orthogonal.
   - They are called the *principal components* of $X$.
2. $V$ is a $p \times p$ matrix.

   - The columns of $V$ have length $1$.
   - The columns of $V$ are mutually orthogonal.
   - This makes $V$ a *rotation* of $\mathbb{R}^p$.
3. $D$ is a *diagonal* $p \times p$ matrix.

   - The diagonal elements $d_{11}, d_{22}, \ldots, d_{pp}$ are not negative.  These are the *singular values* of $X$.
   - If we wish, we may order them from largest to smallest.

Criteria (1) and (2) assert that both $U$ and $V$ are *orthonormal* matrices.  They can be neatly summarized by the conditions

$$U^\prime U = 1_p,\ V^\prime V = 1_p.$$

As a consequence (that $V$ represents a rotation), $VV^\prime = 1_p$ also.  This will be used in the Ridge Regression derivation below.

##What it does for us

***It can simplify formulas.***  This works both algebraically and conceptually.  Here are some examples.

###The Normal Equations

Consider the regression $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ where, as usual, the $\varepsilon$ are independent and identically distributed according to a law that has zero expectation and finite variance $\sigma^2$.  The least squares solution via the Normal Equations is $$\hat\beta = (X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime y.$$  Applying the SVD and simplifying the resulting algebraic mess (which is easy) provides a nice insight:

$$(X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime = ((UDV^\prime)^\prime (UDV^\prime))^{-1} (UDV^\prime)^\prime \\= (VDU^\prime U D V^\prime)^{-1} (VDU^\prime) = VD^{-2}V^\prime VDU^\prime = VD^{-1}U^\prime.$$

The only difference between this and $X^\prime = VDU^\prime$ is that the reciprocals of the elements of $D$ are used!  In other words, the "equation" $y=X\beta$ is solved by "inverting" $X$: this pseudo-inversion undoes the rotations $U$ and $V^\prime$ (merely by transposing them) and undoes the multiplication (represented by $D$) separately in each principal direction.

For future reference, notice that "rotated" estimates $V^\prime \hat\beta $ are linear combinations of "rotated" responses $U^\prime y$.  The coefficients are inverses of the (positive) diagonal elements of $D$, equal to $d_{ii}^{-1}$.

###Covariance of the coefficient estimates

Recall that the covariance of the estimates is $$\text{Cov}(\hat\beta) = \sigma^2(X^\prime X)^{-1}.$$  Using the SVD, this becomes $$\sigma^2(V D^2 V^\prime)^{-1} = \sigma^2 V D^{-2} V^\prime.$$  In other words, the covariance acts like that of $k$ *orthogonal* variables, each with variances $d^2_{ii}$, that have been rotated in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

###The Hat matrix

The hat matrix is $$H = X(X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime.$$ By means of the preceding result we may rewrite it as $$H = (UDV^\prime)(VD^{-1}U^\prime) = UU^\prime.$$ Simple!

###Eigenanalysis (spectral decomposition)

Since $$X^\prime X = VDU^\prime U D V^\prime = VD^2V^\prime$$ and $$XX^\prime = UDV^\prime VDU^\prime = UD^2U^\prime,$$ it is immediate that

- The eigenvalues of $X^\prime X$ and $XX^\prime$ are the squares of the singular values.
- The columns of $V$ are the eigenvectors of $X^\prime X$.
- The columns of $U$ are some of the eigenvectors of $X X^\prime$.  (Other eigenvectors exist but correspond to zero eigenvalues.)

**SVD can diagnose and solve collinearity problems.**

###Approximating the regressors

When you replace the smallest singular values with zeros, you will change the product $UDV^\prime$ only slightly.  Now, however, the zeros eliminate the corresponding columns of $U$, **effectively reducing the number of variables.**  Provided those eliminated columns have little correlation with $y$, **this can work effectively as a variable-reduction technique.**

##Ridge Regression

Let the columns of $X$ be standardized, as well as $y$ itself.  (This means we no longer need a constant column in $X$.)  For $\lambda \gt 0$ the ridge estimator is  $$\begin{aligned}\hat\beta_R &= (X^\prime X + \lambda)^{-1}X^\prime y \\
&= (VD^2V^\prime + \lambda\,1_p)^{-1}VDU^\prime y \\
&=  (VD^2V^\prime + \lambda V V^\prime)^{-1}VDU^\prime y \\
&= (V(D^2 + \lambda)V^\prime)^{-1} VDU^\prime y \\
&= V(D^2+\lambda)^{-1}V^\prime V DU^\prime y \\
&= V(D^2 + \lambda)^{-1} D U^\prime y.\end{aligned}$$

**The difference between this and $\hat\beta$ is the replacement of $D^{-1} = D^{-2}D$ by $(D^2+\lambda)^{-1}D$.** In effect, this multiplies the original by the fraction $D^2/(D^2+\lambda)$.  Because (when $\lambda \gt 0$) the denominator is obviously greater than the numerator, *the parameter estimates "shrink towards zero."*

---

This result has to be understood in the somewhat subtle sense alluded to previously: the *rotated* estimates $V^\prime\hat\beta_R$ are still linear combinations of the vectors $U^\prime y$, but each coefficient--which used to be $d_{ii}^{-1}$--has been multiplied by a factor of $d_{ii}^2/(d_{ii}^2 + \lambda)$.  As such, the *rotated* coefficients must shrink, but it is possible, when $\lambda$ is sufficiently small, for some of the $\hat\beta_R$ themselves actually to increase in size.

To avoid distractions, the case of one of more zero singular values was excluded in this discussion.  In such circumstances, *if we conventionally take "$d_{ii}^{-1}$" to be zero,* then everything still works.  This is what is going on when [generalized inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Linear_least-squares) are used to solve the Normal equations.

Comment: +1. A small terminological note: I would say that columns of $U$ are called "principal components" (as you wrote in the beginning) only if columns of $X$ have been centered.

Comment: @amoeba What would you call them otherwise? What would you call them if no nonzero constant vector were within the column space of $X$?

Comment: When you say "the denominator is obviously greater than the numerator", what is intended as denominator and numerator? -- is $D$ the numerator and $D^2+\lambda$ the denominator? If that was what you meant, how do we know that $D^2$ is not smaller than $D$ and/or that $\lambda$ isn't smaller than the difference between their diagonals?

Comment: If columns of $X$ are not centered, then I guess I'd simply say "left singular vectors". If I think of a 2D data cloud stretched from north to south but located far to the east, then the first principal component will be projection on the vertical axis, but the first left singular vector will be projection on the horizontal axis. It feels strange to refer to the latter as "principal component".

Comment: @whuber 1- I am not sure what this 'The columns of U have length 1' means ? 2- why vv' is equals I.

Comment: (1) Part of the equation $UU^\prime=1_p$ asserts that the dot product of each column of $U$ with itself is $1$, whence each length is (by definition) $\sqrt{1}=1$. (2) $VV^\prime=1_p$ follows from the observation that $V$ is a rotation matrix, because this implies $V^{-1}$ is also a rotation matrix. Therefore $(V^{-1})^\prime(V^{-1})=1_p$. Plugging in $V^{-1}=V^\prime$ gives $VV^\prime=(V^\prime)^\prime V^\prime=1_p$.

Comment: +1 For completeness sake, it would be good to define $\sigma^2$ when defining the covariance matrix of estimated parameters.

Comment: @ whuber, I have question. Now as I understood for any matrix $$X = UDV^\prime$$ . While, for the symmetric matrix it will be  $$X = UDU^\prime$$. I am confused between the two theorems, could you please clarify that.

Comment: When $X$ is symmetric, then by definition $$VDU^\prime=X^\prime=X=UDV^\prime.$$  Comparing the left and right sides immediately shows the diagonalization of a real symmetric matrix is a special case of the SVD and also suggests that in the SVD of a symmetric matrix, $U=V$.  That in fact is the case provided $X$ is nondegenerate--but proving it is not entirely elementary, so I won't go into details.

Comment: @ whuber, If I multiply the ridge solutions by $X$ (i.e. the fitted values) , I got something like this $$V(D^2/D^2+\lambda)U^TY,$$ So I become a little bit confused to what you have explained, could you please clarify that ?

Comment: @jeza I don't see how you can obtain that value when you multiply $X$ by $\hat\beta_R$: you don't seem to have followed the usual rules of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @whuber, my steps are : the ridge solutions is $$\hat{\beta}_{R}=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$$ , When multiply by $X$ , $$X\hat{\beta}_{R}=X(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$$ we know that $(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY= V(D^2+\lambda I)^{-1}DU^TY$, thus the solutions after multiplying by $X$ will be $$U(D^2/(D^2+\lambda))U^TY$$

Comment: @jeza Okay, so what's the problem with that?

Comment: @  whuber, so both my solution and yours are right ? The first shrinks the estimates and the second shrinks the fitted values, because I become a little bit confused for both solutions.

Comment: @jeza Think of it this way: What happens to the fitted values as the parameter estimates shrink towards zero?

Comment: @ whuber, oh , is it like this ? In the fitted value $\hat{y}$ we will use the coefficients estimates and as long as they are shrunk towards zero the same will happen for the fitted value.

Comment: @whuber in my answer to amoeba's [Reversing ridge regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/236232/127790) question I do something similar, but for the under-determined $X$ case ($n<p$). I have a note "... derivation omitted for the sake of brevity", and amoeba suggested to link here. Does this seem appropriate to you? (and/or is there better CV answer to point to?)

Comment: A more elementary analysis of Ridge regression is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/297475/919.  @GeoMatt The only place I used the assumption $p \le n$ was in the initial description of the SVD.  So, when $p \gt n$, apply the SVD to $X^\prime$, transpose it to obtain $X=VDU^\prime$ (thereby switching the roles of $V$ and $U$), and proceed from there.

Comment: @jeza : the confusion is because whuber has a mistake in their presentation. $\hat{\beta}$ is given via the diagonal matrix $(D^2+\lambda I)^{-1} D$ which means you shrink by $d/(d^2+\lambda)$. The predictions, however, have a quadratic behaviour in the numerator. This is a mistake often seen in lectures notes online. I guess someone had a typo one day and it's just being copy pasted around.

Comment: @Jean-LucBouchot Would you be so kind as to indicate what the mistake might be so it could be corrected?  This answer was not copied or pasted from anywhere: it is original, as explained at the outset.  (Have you noted that the original singular value is $D^{-1}$? You seem to overlook that in your comment.)

Comment: The part " by (D2+λ)−1D. In effect, this multiplies the original by the fraction $D^2/(D^2+\lambda)$" is not correct. It should be a power 1 in the numerator.
However, if you're talking about the predictions, than indeed, you would get a power 2 but then you would get the matrix $U$ and $U'$ on the other side. This is obtained by left multiplying with the data matrix and re-using the SVD.

Comment: @Luc The "original" is $D^{-1},$ so your algebra appears to be incorrect.

Comment: I understand what you mean now :) 
I thought you meant you multiply the (projected) elements with $D^2/(D^2+\lambda)$. What you're (rightfully) saying is that you multiply the original (non regularized) $D^{-1}$ with the $D^2/(D^2+\lambda)$. 

Both our algebras are correct. My reading, however, needs to be improved! My apologies!

Comment: the link to the notes is now broken

Comment: Thanks -- I had to remove it, because the course notes are no longer on the Web.