# Reversing ridge regression: given response matrix and regression coefficients, find suitable predictors

Tags: regression, least-squares, ridge-regression

Consider a standard OLS regression problem$\newcommand{\Y}{\mathbf Y}\newcommand{\X}{\mathbf X}\newcommand{\B}{\boldsymbol\beta}\DeclareMathOperator*{argmin}{argmin}$: I have matrices $\Y$ and $\X$ and I want to find $\B$ to minimize $$L=\|\Y-\X\B\|^2.$$
The solution is given by $$\hat\B=\argmin_\B\{L\} = (\X^\top\X)^+\X^\top \Y.$$

I can also pose a "reverse" problem: given $\Y$ and $\B^*$, find $\hat\X$ that would yield  $\hat\B\approx \B^*$, i.e. would minimize $\|\argmin_\B\{L\}-\B^*\|^2$. In words, I have the response matrix $\Y$ and the coefficient vector $\B^*$ and I want to find the predictor matrix that would yield coefficients close to $\B^*$. This is, of course, also an OLS regression problem with solution $$\hat\X = \argmin_\X\Big\{\|\argmin_\B\{L\}-\B^*\|^2\Big\} = \Y\B^\top(\B\B^\top)^{+}.$$

**Clarification update:** As @GeoMatt22 explained in his answer, if $\Y$ is a vector (i.e. if there is only one response variable), then this $\hat \X$ will be rank one, and the reverse problem is massively underdetermined. In my case, $\Y$ is actually a matrix (i.e. there are many response variables, it is a *multivariate* regression). So $\X$ is $n\times p$, $\Y$ is $n\times q$ and $\B$ is $p\times q$.

---

**I am interested in solving a "reverse" problem for ridge regression.** Namely, my loss function now is $$L=\|\Y-\X\B\|^2+\mu\|\B\|^2$$
and the solution is $$\hat\B=\argmin_\B\{L\}=(\X^\top \X+\mu\mathbf I)^{-1}\X^\top \Y.$$

The "reverse" problem is to find $$\hat\X = \argmin_\X\Big\{\|\argmin_\B\{L\}-\B^*\|^2\Big\} = \;?$$

Again, I have a response matrix $\Y$ and a coefficient vector $\B^*$ and  I want to find a predictor matrix that would yield coefficients close to $\B^*$.

Actually there are two related formulations:

1. Find $\hat\X$ given $\Y$ and $\B^*$ and $\mu$.
2. Find $\hat\X$ and $\hat \mu$ given $\Y$ and $\B^*$.

Does either of them have a direct solution?

---

Here is a brief Matlab excerpt to illustrate the problem:

```matlab
% generate some data
n = 10; % number of samples
p = 20; % number of predictors
q = 30; % number of responses
Y = rand(n,q);
X = rand(n,p);
mu = 0;
I = eye(p);

% solve the forward problem: find beta given y,X,mu
betahat = pinv(X'*X + mu*I) * X'*Y;

% backward problem: find X given y,beta,mu
% this formula works correctly only when mu=0
Xhat =  Y*betahat'*pinv(betahat*betahat');

% verify if Xhat indeed yields betahat
betahathat = pinv(Xhat'*Xhat + mu*I)*Xhat'*Y;
max(abs(betahathat(:) - betahat(:)))
```

This code outputs zero if `mu=0` but not otherwise.

Comment: Since $B$ and $\mu$ are given, they don't affect variations in the loss.  Therefore in (1) you are *still* doing OLS.  (2) is equally simple, because the loss can be made arbitrarily small by taking $\hat\mu$ arbitrarily negative, within the limits of any constraints you compare to impose on it.  That reduces you to case (1).

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I think I did not explain it clear enough. Consider (1). $B$ and $\mu$ are given  (let's call it $B^*$), but I need to find $X$ that would yield ridge regression coefficients close to $B^*$, in other words I want to find $X$ minimizing $$\Big\|\operatorname*{argmin}_B\big\{ L_\mathrm{ridge}(X,B)\big\} - B^*\Big\|^2.$$ I don't see why this should be OLS.

Comment: It's like I have $f(v,w)$ and I want to find $v$ such that $\operatorname{argmin}_w f(v,w)$ is close to a given $w^*$. It is not the same as finding $\operatorname{argmin}_v f(v,w^*)$.

Comment: The exposition in your post is confusing about that matter, because evidently you are *not* actually using $L$ as a loss function.  Could you perhaps elaborate on the specifics of problems (1) and (2) in the post?

Comment: Yes, let me edit. I can see that it is confusing.

Comment: should we use $\beta$ instead of $B$? $\mathbf B$ seems to be matrix instead of vector.

Comment: @hxd1011 It *is* a matrix, because $Y$ is a matrix too. It's multivariate regression. But I don't think this is important for the problem, because multivariate ridge regression is equivalent to a set of univariate ones. I think I will edit to make it univariate for simplicity. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, Also I think I also have different impression about "multivariate regression", usually that means $\mathbf X$ has more than one columns, but $\mathbf y$ is still a vector but not a matrix. What you were talking seems to be something like "multiple prediction target" instead of "multivariate"?

Comment: @hxd1011 Many columns in X is usually called "multiple regression", many columns in Y is usually called "multivariate regression".

Comment: @hxd1011 I can imagine that this terminology might differ... But this is rather standard I believe. Anyway, I edited everything to the univariate case.

Comment: @amoeba if there are particular constraints on the dimensions, you should put that in the question, i.e. $n<p<q$.

Comment: @hxd1011 after several iterations I think I am finally clear on exactly what the problem of interest is. In my updated answer I tried to clarify the notation: For the forward problem, the matrix variant of the least squares problem is equivalent to a sequence of vector problems for $y_1,\ldots,y_q$. This is commonly known as "multiple right hand sides".

Comment: @amoeba in your code, why use `pinv`? it is not numerically stable, using [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) is better. see [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)

Comment: @hxd1011 this is off topic, but the one time I found a use for explicitly computing a matrix (pseudo-)inverse was to derive some [moving least-squares filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Derivation_of_convolution_coefficients) for image processing. Now, the systems were small, and in Matlab I actually did literally compute $A^+$ as `A\I` :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now that the question has converged on a more precise formulation of the problem of interest, I have found a solution for case 1 (known ridge parameter). This should also help for case 2 (not an analytical solution exactly, but a simple formula and some constraints).

> **Summary:** Neither of the two inverse problem formulations has a unique answer. In **case 2**, where the ridge parameter $\mu\equiv\omega^2$ is unknown, there are infinitely many solutions $X_\omega$, for $\omega\in[0,\omega_\max]$. In case 1, where $\omega$ is given, there are a finite number of solutions for $X_\omega$, due to ambiguity in the singular-value spectrum.

(The derivation is a bit lengthy, so TL,DR: there is a working Matlab code at the end.)

---

**Under-determined Case ("OLS")**

The forward problem is
$$\min_B\|XB-Y\|^2$$
where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$, and $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$.

Based on the updated question, we will assume $n<p<q$, so $B$ is under determined given $X$ and $Y$. As in the question, we will assume the "default" (minimum $L_2$-norm) solution 
$$B=X^+Y$$
where $X^+$ is the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $X$.

From the singular value decomposition ([SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) of $X$, given by*
$$X=USV^T=US_0V_0^T$$
the pseudoinverse can be computed as**
$$X^+=VS^+U^T=V_0S_0^{-1}U^T$$
(*The first expressions use the full SVD, while the second expressions use the reduced SVD. **For simplicity I assume $X$ has full rank, i.e. $S_0^{-1}$ exists.)

So the forward problem has solution
$$B\equiv X^+Y=\left(V_0S_0^{-1}U^T\right)Y$$
For future reference, I note that $S_0=\mathrm{diag}(\sigma_0)$, where $\sigma_0>0$ is the vector of singular values.

In the inverse problem, we are given $Y$ and $B$. We know that $B$ came from the above process, but we do not know $X$. The task is then to determine the appropriate $X$.

As noted in the updated question, in this case we can recover $X$ using essentially the same approach, i.e.
$$X_0=YB^+$$
now using the pseudoinverse of $B$.

---

**Over-determined Case (Ridge estimator)**

In the "OLS" case, the under-determined problem was solved by choosing the [minimum-norm solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Minimum_norm_solution_to_a_linear_system), i.e. our "unique" solution was implicitly [regularized](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/regularization/info).

Rather than choose the *minimum* norm solution, here we introduce a parameter $\omega$ to control "how small" the norm should be, i.e. we use [ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ridge-regression/info).

In this case, we have a *series* of forward problems for $\beta_k$, $k=1,\ldots,q$, that are given by
$$\min_\beta\|X\beta-y_k\|^2+\omega^2\|\beta\|^2$$
Collecting the different left and right hand side vectors into
$$B_{\omega}=[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k] \quad,\quad Y=[y_1,\ldots,y_k]$$
this collection of problems can be reduced to the following "OLS" problem
$$\min_B\|\mathsf{X}_\omega B-\mathsf{Y}\|^2$$
where we have introduced the augmented matrices
$$\mathsf{X}_\omega=\begin{bmatrix}X \\ \omega I\end{bmatrix}
\quad , \quad \mathsf{Y}=\begin{bmatrix}Y \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

In this over-determined case, the solution is still given by the pseudo-inverse
$$B_\omega = \mathsf{X}^+\mathsf{Y}$$
but the pseudo-inverse is now changed, resulting in*
$$B_\omega = \left(V_0S_\omega^{-2}U^T\right) Y$$
where the new "singularity spectrum" matrix has (inverse) diagonal**
$$ \sigma_\omega^2 = \frac{\sigma_0^2+\omega^2}{\sigma_0} $$
(*The somewhat involved calculation required to derive this has been omitted for the sake of brevity. It is similar to the exposition [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220324/127790) for the $p\leq n$ case. **Here the entries of the $\sigma_\omega$ vector are expressed in terms of the $\sigma_0$ vector, where all operations are entry-wise.)

Now in this problem we can still formally recover a "base solution" as
$$X_\omega=YB_\omega^+$$
but this is not a true solution anymore.

However, the analogy still holds in that this "solution" has SVD
$$X_\omega=US_\omega^2V_0^T$$
with the singular values $\sigma_\omega^2$ given above.

So we can derive a quadratic equation relating the desired singular values $\sigma_0$ to the recoverable singular values $\sigma_\omega^2$ and the regularization parameter $\omega$. The solution is then
$$\sigma_0=\bar{\sigma} \pm \Delta\sigma \quad , \quad \bar{\sigma} = \tfrac{1}{2}\sigma_\omega^2 \quad , \quad \Delta\sigma = \sqrt{\left(\bar{\sigma}+\omega\right)\left(\bar{\sigma}-\omega\right)}$$

---

The Matlab demo below (tested online via [Octave](http://octave-online.net/)) shows that this solution method appears to work in practice as well as theory. The last line shows that all the singular values of $X$ are in the reconstruction $\bar{\sigma}\pm\Delta\sigma$, but I have not completely figured out which root to take (`sgn` = $+$ vs. $-$). For $\omega=0$ it will always be the $+$ root. This generally seems to hold for "small" $\omega$, whereas for "large" $\omega$ the $-$ root seems to take over. (Demo below is set to "large" case currently.)

```matlab
% Matlab demo of "Reverse Ridge Regression"
n = 3; p = 5; q = 8; w = 1*sqrt(1e+1); sgn = -1;
Y = rand(n,q); X = rand(n,p);
I = eye(p); Z = zeros(p,q);
err = @(a,b)norm(a(:)-b(:),Inf);

B = pinv([X;w*I])*[Y;Z];
Xhat0 = Y*pinv(B);
dBres0 = err( pinv([Xhat0;w*I])*[Y;Z] , B )

[Uw,Sw2,Vw0] = svd(Xhat0, 'econ');

sw2 = diag(Sw2); s0mid = sw2/2;
ds0 = sqrt(max( 0 , s0mid.^2 - w^2 ));
s0 = s0mid + sgn * ds0;
Xhat = Uw*diag(s0)*Vw0';

dBres = err( pinv([Xhat;w*I])*[Y;Z] , B )
dXerr = err( Xhat , X )
sigX = svd(X)', sigHat = [s0mid+ds0,s0mid-ds0]' % all there, but which sign?
```

I cannot say how *robust* this solution is, as inverse problems are generally ill-posed, and analytical solutions can be very fragile. However cursory experiments polluting $B$ with Gaussian noise (i.e. so it has full rank $p$ vs. reduced rank $n$) seem to indicate the method is reasonably well behaved.

As for problem 2 (i.e. $\omega$ unknown), the above gives at least an *upper bound* on $\omega$. For the quadratic discriminant to be non-negative we must have
$$\omega \leq \omega_{\max} = \bar{\sigma}_n = 
\min[\tfrac{1}{2}\sigma_\omega^2]$$

---

For the quadratic-root sign ambiguity, the following code snippet shows that independent of sign, any $\hat{X}$ will give the same forward $B$ ridge-solution, even when $\sigma_0$ differs from $\mathrm{SVD}[X]$.

```matlab
Xrnd=Uw*diag(s0mid+sign(randn(n,1)).*ds0)*Vw0'; % random signs
dBrnd=err(pinv([Xrnd;w*I])*[Y;Z],B) % B is always consistent ...
dXrnd=err(Xrnd,X) % ... even when X is not
```

Comment: +11. Thanks a lot for all the effort that you put into answering this question and for all the discussion that we had. This seems to answer my question entirely. I felt that simply accepting your answer is not enough in this case; this deserves much more than two upvotes that this answer currently has. Cheers.

Comment: @amoeba thanks! I am glad it was helpful. I think I will post a comment on whuber's answer you link asking if he thinks it is appropriate and/or if there is a better answer to use. (Note he prefaces his SVD discussion with the proviso $p\leq n$, i.e. an over-determined $X$.)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 my comment on original question says using `pinv` is not a good thing, do you agree?

Comment: @hxd1011 In general you (almost) never want to explicitly invert a matrix numerically, and this holds also for the pseudo-inverse. The two reasons I used it here are 1) consistency with the mathematical equations + amoeba's demo code, and 2) for the case of underdetermined systems, the default Matlab "slash" solutions can [differ from the pinv ones](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html). Almost all of the cases in my code could be replaced by the appropriate \ or / commands, which are generally to be preferred. (These allow Matlab to decide the most effective direct solver.)

Comment: @hxd1011 to clarify on point 2 of my previous comment, from the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) in your comment on the original question: "If the rank of A is less than the number of columns in A, then x = A\B is not necessarily the minimum norm solution. The more computationally expensive x = pinv(A)*B computes the minimum norm least-squares solution.".