# How to derive the covariance matrix of $\hat\beta$ in linear regression?

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix

I just read this very insightful post [about ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220243/the-proof-of-shrinking-coefficients-using-ridge-regression-through-spectral-dec), where the author stated that the variance of $\hat\beta$ is:

$$\text{var}(\hat\beta) = \sigma^2(\textbf{X}^\prime \textbf{X})^{-1}.$$

I couldn't figure out why it is like this. Can anyone elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 5):

The covariance result you are looking at occurs under a standard regression model using ordinary least-squares (OLS) estimation.  The OLS estimator (written as a random variable) is given by:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} 
&= (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{Y}) \\[6pt]
&= (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} (\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) \\[6pt]
&= \boldsymbol{\beta} + (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In the standard linear regression model we have $\mathbb{E}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \boldsymbol{0}$ and $\mathbb{V}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{I}$  so that the estimator is unbiased with covariance matrix given by:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{V}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}) 
&= \mathbb{V}((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) \\[6pt]
&= ((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} ) \mathbb{V}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) ((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} )^{\text{T}} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 ((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} ) \boldsymbol{I} ((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} )^{\text{T}} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 ((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} ) ((\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} )^{\text{T}} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1} (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x}) (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1}  \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 (\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}} \boldsymbol{x})^{-1}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Note that this is the conditional covariance of the estimator given the design matrix $\boldsymbol{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Four things to note:

$\hat{\beta} =(\textbf{X}^\prime\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^\prime\textbf{Y}$

$\text{var}({\textbf{A}\textbf{Y}})=\textbf{A}\text{var}(\textbf{Y})\textbf{A}^\prime$

$\text{var}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X})=\sigma^2\textbf{I}$ (actually, everything is conditioned on $\textbf{X}$)

$(\textbf{X}^\prime\textbf{X})^{-1}$ is symmetric.

Comment: $\text{var}(Y) \neq \sigma^2\textbf{I}$, unless $Y$ is the error term (or $\beta = 0$).

Comment: @jbowman thank you, I edited to condition on $\textbf{X}$