# $L^2$ Regularization and Hessian Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regularization, tikhonov-regularization

[image: Deep learning Book by Goodfellow]

In the second paragraph it is mentioned that eigenvector of $H$ is rescaled by a factor of $\frac{\lambda_i} {\lambda_i +\alpha}$ What exactly meant by that ?

Comment: Can you work out the answer if you write down the inverse of $$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 
\end{bmatrix} + \alpha I?
$$

Comment: This is explained at the end of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220324/919.

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax for your great answers. This solved my ambiguity. :)