# Intuition behind the degrees of freedom in ridge regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, intuition, ridge-regression, degrees-of-freedom

I'm reading through the ESL book and I'm on the part of ridge regression where the effective degrees of freedom are defined
$$
df(\lambda) = tr(X(X'X + \lambda I)^{-1}X') = \sum_{j=1}^p{\frac{d_j^2}{d_j^2 + \lambda}}
$$

I have no idea where this is coming from, what's the idea and intuition behind it.

Comment: For the derivation of the terms in the sum see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220324/919.  The interpretation of their sum as a "degrees of freedom" originates in the trace of the (usual) "hat matrix" $H.$