# When there are more variables than observations do shrinkage methods (such as Ridge and Lasso) always find a solution?

Tags: regression, least-squares, lasso, ridge-regression

Assume we have $n$ observations and $p$ explanatory variables we want to model. To apply ridge regression, we choose a constraint parameter $\lambda \geq 0$ and estimate the coefficients $\beta_i$ which minimise:

\begin{equation} \sum^{n}_{i=1} \left( y_i - \beta_o - \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_jx_{ij} \right) + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j^2 \end{equation}

where $y_i$ are the observations and $x_{ij}$ are the variables.

I am reading an Introduction to Statistical Learning, which says:

> When λ = 0, the penalty term has no effect, and ridge regression will produce the least squares estimates

and (of ridge regression):

> if p > n, then the least squares estimates do not even have a unique solution, whereas ridge regression can still perform well

My questions are the following:

1. Am I correct in saying that ridge regression (and lasso) fail when $p > n$ and $\lambda = 0$, due to being equivalent to least squares?
2. If so, is there a solution for all $\lambda > 0$ when $p > n$, particularly when $\lambda$ is very close to zero?
3. If there is a solution for all $\lambda > 0$ when $p>n$, is there some reason to be wary of applying shrinkage methods like this due to the closeness of the optimisation problem to least squares?

Comment: When you ask "do they work", do you actually mean "do they work *well*"? There are all kinds of reasons why they may not work well in certain situations, even if they work in the sense that you get a solution.

Comment: I see, I did mean 'do they work' to mean 'is there a solution'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, $p>n, \lambda=0$ case is rank-deficient. Since you already  know that OLS for $p>n$ is rank-deficient, then we can see that substituting $\lambda = 0$ in your equation gives the same objective as OLS, and the proof is complete.
2. Yes, ridge regression works for any $\lambda >0$. The immediate demonstration is that the $\lambda I$ is positive definite, so $\lambda I + X^T X$ must be positive definite. You can alternatively show this by applying SVD, and showing that the singular values in the ridge case are all positive. [The proof of shrinking coefficients using ridge regression through "spectral decomposition"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220243/the-proof-of-shrinking-coefficients-using-ridge-regression-through-spectral-dec) However, as a matter of doing computation on a computer (not mathematics), choosing $\lambda$ too small may not work because floating point arithmetic is not exact.
3. This is essentially a question of [bias-variance-tradeoff](/questions/tagged/bias-variance-tradeoff). If we choose $\lambda$ too large, then there is too steep a penalty on the coefficients and our predictions may be too far from reality to be useful. If we choose $\lambda$ too small, then the variance of the model may be too high -- estimates will be strongly influenced by our specific data set. In the extreme, excluding or including a single datum could radically change the coefficient estimates.